# Tensorflow's tf.nn.conv2d_transpose parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Recently I have been trying to understand tensorflow's `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`, however I have a hard time understanding the input parameters for it. It's defined as:

```
tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value, filter, output_shape, strides, padding='SAME')
```

For example, let's say I have a image of size `[batch_size, 7, 7, 128]` and want to transform it to `[batch_size, 14, 14, 64]`. Then `output_shape=[batch_size, 14, 14, 64]`, `strides=[2,2]`, however I can't figure out how to get the shape of the filter. Any thoughts?

Furthermore how does `padding="SAME"` works for `conv2d_transpose`? Is it applied to the output image or the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question on filter shapes, I'd use the object oriented version [`tf.layers.Conv2DTranspose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Conv2DTranspose) and look at the `kernel` property to figure out the filter shapes:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> l = tf.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=1, padding='SAME', strides=[2, 2])
>>> l(tf.ones([12, 7, 7, 128]))
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose/BiasAdd:0' shape=(12, 14, 14, 64) dtype=float32>
>>> l.kernel
<tf.Variable 'conv2d_transpose/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1, 64, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
>>>
```

On second padding question, `conv2d_transpose` computes the gradient of `conv2d`. Since `conv2d` pads its inputs, `conv2d_transpose` needs to pad its output to fit the gradient.